# forecasting function FORECAST.ETS in excel does not work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, forecasting

So I have table that looks like this:

```
     A         B
Mar 31 2013 -0.0253
Apr 07 2013 0.0215
Apr 14 2013 -0.0153
Apr 21 2013 0.0222
Apr 28 2013 0.0148
May 05 2013 0.0159
May 12 2013 0.0148
May 19 2013 -0.0102
May 26 2013 -0.0107
Jun 02 2013 -0.026
Jun 09 2013 -0.0162
Jun 16 2013 -0.0305
Jun 23 2013 0.0162
Jun 30 2013 0.0258
Jul 07 2013 0.0266
Jul 14 2013 0.0131
Jul 21 2013 -0.0114
Jul 28 2013 0.0142
Aug 04 2013 -0.0097


Aug 20 2013 #VALUE!
```

First column is data and second is value. I try to `Forecast` value for `August 20th 2013`, but I always get error...

> My function for forecasting

```
=FORECAST.ETS(A58, B37:B55, A37:A55)
```

When I  inspect error, it underlines `A58`, so I assume something is wrong with the format?? My `A column` has date type and `b column` has number type. Can someone explain why it throws error??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those dates are not real dates but text-that-look-like-dates. Select all of the dates and use either text-to-Columns, Delimited, No delimiter, MDY, Finish or Replace (Ctrl+H) `201` with `, 201`.

The first thing you should notice is that all of the dates are now right-aligned the way dates and numbers should be. Text (or text-that-look-like-dates) is left-aligned by default.

[image]